# Why is my usage of command TASKLIST not working as expected?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, tasklist

I have a problem on checking the running state of another batch file using the command **TASKLIST** and continue processing the batch file depending on the result.

This is the code of my batch file which should check the running state of the other batch file:

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe - C:\ruta\ejecucion_prueba.bat" /FI "STATUS eq running"
if eq = running "not happening"
if ne = running "start  C:\ruta\ejecucion_prueba.bat"
exit
```

This code does not work as expected. The output on execution is:

> INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.
> = was unexpected at this time.

What is wrong and how to do the batch file execution check correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tasklist.exe` does not write to stdErr or record an ErrorLevel you can use, to determine whether the filters returned a task. In order to determine that, you need to use `find.exe` or `findstr.exe` to check for a known character or string in a successful output. You can then use the returned ErrorLevel or Success/Failure of that to validate instead.

The only 'relatively robust' way to perform this task using `tasklist.exe` is to first ensure that you initially ran your batch file, `C:\ruta\ejecucion_prueba.bat` using the following command:

```
Start "?" C:\ruta\ejecucion_prueba.bat
```

Or *(recommended)*:

```
Start "?" "C:\ruta\ejecucion_prueba.bat"
```

With that done, you could run your verification batch file, with the following line in its content:

```batch-file
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /Fi "ImageName Eq cmd.exe" /Fi "Status Eq Running" /Fi "WindowTitle Eq ? - C:\ruta\ejecucion_prueba.bat" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "=" 1> NUL || Start "?" "C:\ruta\ejecucion_prueba.bat"
```

However, if your batch file path contains spaces:

```
C:\ruta\ejecucion prueba.bat
```

You'd need to have initially ran it using:

```
Start "?" "C:\ruta\ejecucion prueba.bat"
```

Then change the command in your batch script to:

```batch-file
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /Fi "ImageName Eq cmd.exe" /Fi "Status Eq Running" /Fi "WindowTitle Eq ? - \"C:\ruta\ejecucion prueba.bat\"" | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "=" 1> NUL || Start "?" "C:\ruta\ejecucion prueba.bat"
```

Note: Regarding your previous intention to run this indefinitely, *(which I do not recommend)*. When you `start` your `.bat` file, the Window Title, does not immediately register within `tasklist.exe`. That means, were you to run this in a loop or through a scheduled task, it is possible that the delay may cause your script to believe that the batch file isn't running, when in fact it is.